# Aggressive torrent client overpowering home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bittorrent

Is it possible to configure a torrent client so aggressively that it somehow overpowers a home network? Specifically in a way OTHER than how the limitation on your ISP bandwith is concerned? What kinds of symptoms can one experience? Are there settings that are known/guaranteed to affect service?

I heard stories about this, and all kinds of symptoms, like where wireless quits working, but Ethernet keeps working, but I've never seen definitive examples or proof.

I'm asking not so I can configure my client to do such a thing,its merely so I can be aware of more conditions that can bring a network to it's knees. Things I would check for when troubleshooting. I know I can learn something from each and every thoughtful example.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes; its possible to saturate your network.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup QoS on your router and give prio to all p2p packets. 
In long run you wont be able to get on any webpages, and sometimes if you use some chines routers you could make overflow your router and it will disconnect for few second.
You will see that when peer/seeders will drop dramaticly.

Sometimes when you flood the ISP it cut some of the packeges for you and p2p drop to few Kb/s sadly (probably flood control system aka DoS prevention)

Comment: Anyway it won't increase the bandwidth above the ISP limit, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Noway.

Given that you get your bandwidth from an ISP you won't ever exceed the bandwidth they provide for you.

You may ask why sometimes there are some fluctuations in bandwidth? (Specially raises)

Answer: depending on the ISP policy, they may give you a shared bandwidth or a dedicated. In shared type sometimes you'll get more bandwidth **if available**.

What's the roll of a download manager (typcialy a torrent client)? They have some policies including concurrent connections, adding state (specially to stateless protocols like TCP),... that make the general process easier for the user.